# How to handle database changes with older version of application

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, nhibernate

I am working on a desktop application(WPF) which is using sql server database to store and fetch the data. Now due to change in user requirement, there are some extra columns added in some tables and I have made changes in NHibernate mapping classes as well and application is ready for new release.

Now if I make database related changes in Production environment, the users who are using old version of the application will get NHibernate exception since the mappings are changed.

Is there any solution to avoid these kind of scenarios? Please need suggestions.

Comment: Depending of the application maybe you can make a test routine to test compliance between application and DB at initialization and raise a proper error like "This version of the app cannot connect with this version of DB for the configured server/base. Please update app"

Answer (score 0):

You should need to do manually. I have experience like this case.

1.Take backup for those table in production server which tables are all you changed mapping and altered new columns.
2.Drop those tables from production server.
3.move local tables schema (tables which you have mapping and new columns) into production server.
4.Now move the production data from backup table into source table based on mapping.